# OnError not shown the default image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a default image when the other specified in `src` doesn't exists, so I did:

```
<img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/' + user.id + '.png" onerror="this.src='+"assets/img/default-avatar.png"+'"></div>';
```

the problem is that I still get the broken thumbnail. Strange thing is that: if I switch the src, so I place `assets/img/default-avatar.png` in the `src` all works well, any idea?

Comment: what these `+` sign means?

Comment: @MaheerAli concatenate the string path

Comment: Are you writing this in a JS file?

Comment: @NickParsons yes, I need to concatenate it because it start with  '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that quotes matching:

```
'<img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/' + user.id + '.png" onerror="this.src='+"assets/img/default-avatar.png"+'"></div>';
```

Or, more readable, use the power of [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`<img src=".././uploads/images/avatar/${user.id}.png" onerror="this.src='${"assets/img/default-avatar.png"}'"></div>`;
```

Answer (score 3):

Put like this,

> onerror="javascript:this.src='/assets/img/default-avatar.png'"

OR

> onerror="this.src='/assets/img/default-avatar.png'"

Comment: but in this way I'll get the path outside the string, because it start with '

Comment: @FZs if you try the solution above you will got an error

Comment: @FZ What Error?

Comment: @sfarzoso What the heck? Why are you put HTML in side javascript?

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I need to return html from js